# How to comment a line in Pycharm?

Tags: python, pycharm

What is the keyboard shortcut to comment text in Pycharm?

When I use <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>/</kbd>, I get:

[image: pycharm screenshot]

Comment: what keyboard layout are you using ?

Comment: If you are using mac, `cmd + /` for other OS's Code->Comment with Line Comment (short-cut)

Comment: Are you sure you didn't accidentally hit one key off? `Ctrl` + `.` will produce the result you described.

Comment: Keep in mind if you are using a Cyrillic keyboard or layout, your keys or key locations may be different than a standard QWERTY keyboard for which the shortcuts were designed.

Comment: @Влад Лещук go to `Settings` `>` `Keymap` `>` `Main Menu` `>` `Code` `>` `Folding` `>` `Comment with Line Comment` right click and choose `Add Keyboard Shortcut` as [shown in the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X61gJ.png)

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to your PyCharm settings (`ctrl` + `alt` + `s`) and locate the `Keymap` on the left sidebar.
2. Look up `comment` using the search bar on the top right, and look at the shortcut for `Comment with Line Comment`.
3. Change it to whatever you'd like, and see if it works.

[Ref.](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/configuring-keyboard-and-mouse-shortcuts.html)